# Add a GPUImagePicture on a video

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I'm trying to add a `GPUImagePicture` and a `GPUImageUIElement` on a video.
`GPUImageUIElement` is working, but I've a problem with the `GPUImagePicture` because I only see it on the first frame and then it disappears.

Here's my code:

```
filter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];
[(GPUImageBrightnessFilter *)filter setBrightness:0];

GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter *blendFilter = [[GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter alloc] init];
blendFilter.mix = 1.0;

        GPUImagePicture *overlay = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo.png"] smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];
        GPUImageTransformFilter *transformFilter = [GPUImageTransformFilter new];
        [transformFilter forceProcessingAtSize:CGSizeMake(73, 83)];
        [transformFilter setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.7, 0.7)];
        [overlay addTarget:transformFilter];
        [overlay processImage];

UIView *subview1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
        UILabel *temperaturaText = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(77, 100, 105, 60)];
        temperaturaText.text = @"test";
        [subview1 addSubview:temperaturaText];
 uiElementInput = [[GPUImageUIElement alloc] initWithView:subview1];

[filter addTarget:blendFilter];
[uiElementInput addTarget:blendFilter];
[blendFilter addTarget:filterView];
[overlay addTarget:filterView];

__unsafe_unretained GPUImageUIElement *weakUIElementInput = uiElementInput;

[filter setFrameProcessingCompletionBlock:^(GPUImageOutput *filter, CMTime frameTime) {
     [weakUIElementInput update];
 }];

[blendFilter addTarget:movieWriter];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you define your input picture of `overlay` as a local variable within your setup method. You aren't holding onto a strong reference to it, so it will be deallocated the instant you finish this method, which also will remove the image texture and its output from your processing pipeline.

If you want to hold on to an input image, you need to make `overlay` an instance variable of your class, like you did for your camera or movie input in the above. Then it will persist to be used by the framework as input.

Comment: The problem is the combination of `GPUImageUIElement` and `GPUImagePicture` because if I leave only the `GPUImagePicture` I visualize it properly on all frames of the video, instead of adding the instance of `GPUImageUIElement` I see it just for a frame

Comment: @swifferina - Try again with the latest code in the repository. There was a timing issue with GPUImageUIElement that I believe I've solved now.

Comment: I fixed creating the instance of overlay and not as a local variable, but even with the latest release I see both the `GPUImageUIElement` that the `GPUImagePicture` only for the initial frame and then I can't see them anymore on my video. they disappear. I just can not solve how to see both the `GPUImageUIElement` that the `GPUImagePicture` together. please could you help me?

Comment: I tried also with the code that I post here : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23334745/combine-gpuimageuielement-and-gpuimagepicture) but the video is flashing and I get an error.